# pandas MultiIndex resulting index structure on using xs vs loc between 0.15.2 & 0.18.0

Tags: pandas, multi-index

The index structure on the result of slicing a subset of data using .xs & .loc on DataFrame with MultiIndex seems to have changed between v0.15.2 & 0.18.0.
Please refer to the code-snippet & output got in ipython notebook using different versions of Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
print 'pandas-version: ', pd.__version__
import numpy as np
l1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
l2 = sorted(['foo','bar','baz'])
nrows = len(l1) * len(l2)
s = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random( nrows * 2).reshape(nrows, 2),
                 index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([l1, l2],
                                                 names=['one','two']))

# print s.index
l_all = slice(None)
# get all records matching 'foo' in level=1 using .loc
sub_loc = s.loc[(l_all, 'foo'),:]
print '.loc[(slice(None), "foo")] result:\n', sub_loc, 
print '\n.loc result-index:\n', sub_loc.index

# get all records matching 'foo' in level=1 using .xs()
sub_xs = s.xs('foo', level=1)
print '\n.xs(\'foo\', level=1) result:\n', sub_xs, 
print '\n .xs result index:\n', sub_xs.index
```

### 0.15.2 output

```
#######################
pandas-version:  0.15.2
.loc[(slice(None), "foo")] result:
                0         1
one two                    
A   foo  0.464551  0.372409
B   foo  0.782062  0.268917
C   foo  0.779423  0.787554
D   foo  0.481901  0.232887 
.loc result-index:
one  two
A    foo
B    foo
C    foo
D    foo

.xs('foo', level=1) result:
            0         1
one                    
A    0.464551  0.372409
B    0.782062  0.268917
C    0.779423  0.787554
D    0.481901  0.232887 
 .xs result index:
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], dtype='object')
```

### 0.18.0 output

```
##########################
pandas-version:  0.18.0
.loc[(slice(None), "foo")] result:
                0         1
one two                    
A   foo  0.723213  0.532838
B   foo  0.736941  0.401252
C   foo  0.217131  0.044254
D   foo  0.712824  0.411026 
.loc result-index:
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], [u'bar', u'baz', u'foo']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2]],
           names=[u'one', u'two'])

.xs('foo', level=1) result:
            0         1
one                    
A    0.723213  0.532838
B    0.736941  0.401252
C    0.217131  0.044254
D    0.712824  0.411026 
 .xs result index:
Index([u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], dtype='object', name=u'one')
```

calling `sub_loc.index` seems to return the same MultiIndex structure of the original DataFrame object (inconsistent with v0.15.2), but `sub_xs.index` seems to be consistent with earlier version.

*Note: I'm using [Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 1.8.0 (64-bit)| (default, Feb 16 2016, 09:58:36) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]]*

Comment: the real inconsistency is while accessing `sub_loc.index`, even printing `print sub_loc` seems to behave consistently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, forget my other answer, the bug I filed is totally unrelated.

The right answer is: the "index structure" has *not* changed between the two versions. The only thing that changed is the way the index is *represented* when you print it.

In both cases you have a MultiIndex, with exactly the same levels and values. You are presumably puzzled by the fact that in 0.18.0 it seems to contain "baz" and "bar". But a `MultiIndex` can have level values it actually does not use, because, as in this example, it contained them when it was created, and unused level values are not eliminated when the lines using them are dropped. `sub_loc.index` in 0.15.2 also has "baz" and "bar" inside `levels`, except that the way it is represented when you print it doesn't reveal this.

And by the way, whether a MultiIndex which has been filtered still contains such "obsolete" labels or not is an implementation detail which you typically should not care of. In other words,

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], [u'bar', u'baz', u'foo']],
       labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 2, 2]],
       names=[u'one', u'two'])
```

and

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D'], [u'foo']],
       labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0, 0]],
       names=[u'one', u'two'])
```

are for practical purposes *exactly the same* index, in the sense of "having the same values in the same positions", and hence behaving identically when used for assignments between `Series`, `DataFrame`s...

(As you by now have probably clear, it is the `labels` component of the `MultiIndex` which determines which values of the levels are actually used, and in which positions.)

Comment: thank you @PietroBattiston, I've over-looked the change in `labels`, by looking too long only at `levels` value.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is indeed a bug, which shows up also in simpler settings:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/12827

**EDIT:** well, probably not, since the example I made in the bug behaves the same in 0.14.1.